# Sum of width+borders != width of row2 when browser not 100% size

Tags: html, css, formatting

Rows line up at 100% but is off when zooming
(IE is the only one that does this right... go figure)

issue reproduction @ http://jsfiddle.net/rAQnE/

```
<div class="col1">one</div><div class="col2">two</div><div class="col2">three</div>
<div class="BoxUnder">under</div>
```

css

```
.col1, .col2{
    display: inline-block;    
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    background: #ebebeb;
}
.col1 {
    width: 44px;
}
.col2{
    width: 60px;
}
.BoxUnder { 
    width: 168px;
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    background: #e5e5e5;
}
```

I've spent way too much time on this for being just +/-1 pixel off.
anybody got a solution to this?

Comment: Just in general: I would never ever expect a browser to render anything perfect when the user zooms.

Comment: I think it's difficult to get an exact result on all browsers. If it would work for Firefox, it will break in IE ...